Alternative proof of Apollonius's identity
How does one prove Apollonius's identity without coordinates or the law of cosines (or similar trigonometric laws)? Is there a known rearrangement proof similar to the many such proofs for the Pythagorean theorem?
Consider the identity on the cover of Linear Algebra Done Right.
It is $a^2 + b^2 = \frac{1}{2}c^2 + 2d^2$ in the figure below:
     Z
   / | \
  /  |  \
 /   |   \
W----X----Y

None of the angles are necessarily right and $X$ is the midpoint of $YZ$.



length symbol
line segment




$a$
WZ


$b$
YZ


$c$
WY


$d$
XZ



We can easily prove this using coordinates.
Assign $W$ the coordinates $(-e, 0)$, $Y$ the coordinates $(e, 0)$ and $Z$ the coordinates $(h, k)$.
We get:
$$
a^2 + b^2 = \\
(k^2 + (h+e)^2) + (k^2 + (h-e)^2) = \\
k^2 + h^2 + 2he + e^2 + k^2 + h^2 - 2he + e^2 = \\
2k^2 + 2h^2 + 2e^2 = \\
2e^2 + 2k^2 + 2h^2 = \\
\frac{1}{2}(4e^2) + 2(k^2+h^2) = \\
\frac{1}{2}c^2 + 2d^2
$$
I'm curious what other ways there are to prove this, ideally not using a coordinate system or the law of cosines as used in the second proof given on Wikipedia.
The restriction against using the law of cosines or similar trigonometric laws is ahistorical, since it was known to Euclid.

If you want to proceed with Euclidean geometry then after proving the Pythagoras theorem (via rearrangement, similarity of triangles, etc); you can use it to prove Apollonius’s theorem.
Consider the given geometry of acute $\Delta ABC$ with $D$ bisecting $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CE} \perp \overline {AB}$ where $D, E \in \overline{AB}$.

With $\overline{DE}=m$ and $\overline{CE}=n$, we have by Pythagorean theorem that $$\begin{align}
n^2+m^2&=d^2 && \Delta CED \\
n^2+\left(\frac{c}2-m\right)^2&=b^2 &&\Delta CEA \\
n^2+\left(\frac{c}2+m\right)^2&=a^2 && \Delta CEB
\end{align}$$
Then adding the equations for $\Delta CEA$ and $\Delta CEB$ gives $$2n^2+2m^2+\frac{2c^2}{4} = a^2+b^2$$ where substituting from the equation of $\Delta CED$ gives $$2d^2+\frac{c^2}{2} =a^2+b^2$$ proving the proposition.
Now consider obtuse $\Delta ABC$ with $D$ bisecting $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CE} \perp \overline {AB}$ where $D, E \in \overline{AB}$ (produced as necessary). Again with $\overline{DE}=m$ and $\overline{CE}=n$ we get the same system of equations from using Pythagoras theorem on the same triangles as we did in the acute triangle case so the result holds good for obtuse triangles as well.
